# ListBoxItem with value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, listboxitem

I would like you to ask if it is somehow possible to provide in the `ListBoxItem` the **string that will appear** and the **value to be stored in DB**.
This is indeed possible:

```
ItemSource={Binding MyEnumColleciton}
```

or

```
ItemSource={DynamicResource MyCollection}
```

etc..

but if you image that I have about 100 ListBoxes .. I don't want to have so many different enumerations and other ItemSource collections, I want to write it directly into the ListBoxItem.

This is what I'm talking about:

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyPath1}" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Text1" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Text2" />
</ListBox>

<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyPath2}" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Text3" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Text4" />
</ListBox>

<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=MyPath3}" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}">
    <ListBoxItem Content="Text5" />
    <ListBoxItem Content="Text6" />
</ListBox>

... 100x
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I came up with this:

```
public class ItemSourceProvider
    {
        public IEnumerable<ValueText<int>> GetValues(object o)
        {
            if (o == null) return null;

            switch (o.ToString().ToUpper())
            {
                case "PARAM":
                {
                    return new List<ValueText<int>>() 
                    {
                        new ValueText<int>{Value = 1, Text = "YES"},
                        new ValueText<int>{Value = 2, Text = "PARTIALLY"},
                        new ValueText<int>{Value = 3, Text = "NO"}
                    };
                }
                default: return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ValueText<T>
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public T Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Add a DP into the control's resources:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="testODP" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ItemSourceProvider}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>PARAM</ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>                            
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

And then:

```
<ListBox SelectedValue="{Binding Path=A}" SelectedValuePath="Value" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" DisplayMemberPath="Text" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource testODP}}" />
```

Comment: It's not directly what I wanted.. but.. 
Your opinions  ?